# How to setup LPR on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, printing, network-printer, lpr

I have a Netgear WGPS606 print server. How can I install that printer on my Windows 8 system?

I have enabled the Windows LRP feature. However; when I try to add a printer it only searches locally. Why is this?

Comment: How are you trying to add the printer? Could you describe the steps you have taken?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `Advanced Printer Setup`.

1. Open the Advanced Printer Setup. There are two ways to do this. One is using the Search function (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>) and searching for it. Make sure you select Settings on the right.

   [[image]
   <sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5b4iw.png)

   The other way is to open the Control Panel on the desktop, view `Devices and Printers` and click `Add a printer` at the top of the window.
2. This is essentially the same box as on Windows 7 (and different from the generic 'find devices' on Windows 8). If it finds the printer automatically, great! If not, then click `The printer that I want isn't listed`, and you will see the exact same options as you had on Windows 7.

   [[image]
   <sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQhSO.png)

Comment: Thanks this got me to the bit I needed. It did not auto find the printer so I needed to select that it was not found, option for TCP/IP enter the IP address, then select custom Settings to set as LPR and set queue name.